# Парсинг позиций товара в зависимости от географического местоположения

Tags: python, парсер

Есть вот такой рабочий код, который показывает позицию товара в поисковой выдаче wildberries. проблема в том, что он показывает только выдачу в Москве, а существуют боты, которые делают это в зависимости от географического местоположения. Там несколько фиксированных мест, к примеру СПб и Краснодар. Может подскажет кто, куда смотреть, чтобы сделать также, позиции в зависимости от геолокации

```
def wildberries(id, req):
    s = requests.session()
    s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5771.215 Safari/537.36'})
    count = 1
    while True:
        r = s.get(f"https://search.wb.ru/exactmatch/ru/female/v4/search?TestGroup=no_filters_count&"
                  f"TestID=304&appType=1&curr=rub&dest=123585809&page={count}&"
                  f"query={req}&regions=80,38,83,4,64,33,68,70,30,40,86,75,69,1,66,110,22,31,48,71,114"
                  f"&resultset=catalog&sort=popular&spp=31&suppressSpellcheck=false&uclusters=2")
        print(r)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        container = loads(soup.find_all()[0].text)
        print(count)
        print(len(container))
        if len(container) == 0:
            return "По вашему запросу товара на сайте не найдено"
        for i in range(len(container["data"]["products"])):
            if int(id) == int(container["data"]["products"][i]['id']):
                return f'Товар по запросу "{req}" находится на {count} странице на {i + 1} месте'
        count += 1

# Разбиваем текст пользователя на массив и проверяем его на нужный нам запрос
arr = message.text.split(" - ",2)
if len(arr) == 2 and arr[0].isdigit():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, wildberries(arr[0], arr[1]), reply_markup=after_res_in_position_markup)
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите в одной строке через тире id товара - ключевой запрос. К примеру:\n\n"
                                      "1234567 - футболка белая")
```

Comment: прокси поставь на нужной локации

Comment: или куки подсунь с выбранным городом